# Sorting an Array of JavaScript Objects a Specific Order (using existing function)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting, underscore.js

Given an array of objects:

```
{
    key: "a",
    value: 42
},
{
    key: "d",
    value: 28
},
{
    key: "c",
    value: 92
},
{
    key: "b",
    value: 87
}
```

and an array of keys:

```
["c", "a", "b", "d"]
```

Is there a ECMAScript function or a 3rd-party JavaScript library that lets you sort - **in one line/function call** - the first array of objects, to **match the order of the keys** specified in the second array, such that the result is:

```
{
    key: "c",
    value: 92
},
{
    key: "a",
    value: 42
},
{
    key: "b",
    value: 87
},
{
    key: "d",
    value: 28
}
```

Other questions that provide a function or algorithm:

- [Javascript - sort array based on another array - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13304543/javascript-sort-array-based-on-another-array)
- [javascript - How do I sort an array of objects based on the ordering of another array? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755889/how-do-i-sort-an-array-of-objects-based-on-the-ordering-of-another-array)

Similar/related questions:

- [Sorting an Array of Objects in PHP In a Specific Order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355550/sorting-an-array-of-objects-in-php-in-a-specific-order)
- [php - Sort array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122062/sort-array-of-objects)

Comment: Have you tried using a combination of array.sort(function()) and insertion sort/selection sort? or you just need a third party solution?

Comment: I found a couple of other questions with solutions after posting this, and updated the question.  So now the goal is to find something that provides it out of the box, rather than re-implementing it.

Comment: _Is there a ECMAScript function or a 3rd-party JavaScript library that lets you..._ is a shopping question and will be closed as such.

Comment: I am baffled as to why this question is being voted for closure.

Comment: if there were a native way to do it, someone would have mentioned it in one of the other questions.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Just use `indexOf` to convert the key to the correct order:

```
var order = ["c", "a", "b", "d"];
_.sortBy(arr, function(obj){ 
    return _.indexOf(order, obj.key);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sTwVD/1/)

If there are a lot of keys, then it would be advantageous to make a hash-map out of the array, like:

```
var order = ["c", "a", "b", "d"];
var orderMap = {};
_.each(order, function(i) { orderMap[i] = _.indexOf(order, i); });
```

This makes the key-sorting lookup constant time rather than O(n).  ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sTwVD/6/))

Comment: Awesome answer. So simple.

Comment: I like this.  It would still be nice to find it in an existing library is a single function.  I'm using CoffeeScript, so this actually makes a nice one-liner: `arr = _.sortBy arr, (obj) -> _.indexOf order, obj.key`.

Comment: @mkopala you can add your own functions to underscore using _.mixin()  http://underscorejs.org/#mixin

Comment: This example was not really clear for me. Here is an additional example that made it clear for me, http://jsfiddle.net/vsn32xp3/.

Comment: Here is [another version](http://jsfiddle.net/sTwVD/41/) which supports arranging array items that are not included in the `order` array to be re-ordered at the back of the sorted array. In your version, items that are not included in the `order` array are placed at the front of the sorted array.

Comment: The `orderMap` can also be created directly with `_.invert(order)`.

Answer (score 39):

Great answers provided so far. Thought that the following may also be an alternative solution in plain JS:

```
var arr = arr.sort(function(a,b) {
    return order.indexOf( a.key ) - order.indexOf( b.key );
    //for the sake of recent versions of Google Chrome use:
    //return a.key.charCodeAt(0) > b.key.charCodeAt(0); or return a.key.charCodeAt(0) - b.key.charCodeAt(0);
});
```

```js
var arr = [
    {
        key: "a",
        value: 42
    },
    {
        key: "d",
        value: 28
    },
    {
        key: "c",
        value: 92
    },
    {
        key: "b",
        value: 87
    }
];

var order = ["c", "a", "b", "d"];

console.log( 'Original: ', JSON.stringify( arr ) );

var arr = arr.sort(function(a,b) {
      return order.indexOf( a.key ) - order.indexOf( b.key );
});

console.log( 'Ordered: ', JSON.stringify( arr ) );
```

Comment: In Chrome 60, I am unable to return a boolean directly from the sort callback, and I need to instead return one of `-1`, `0` or `1`.

Comment: @BardiHarborow, how about `return a.key.charCodeAt(0) > b.key.charCodeAt(0);` or `return a.key.charCodeAt(0) - b.key.charCodeAt(0);`?

Comment: I am pretty sure this should be `order.indexOf( a.key ) - order.indexOf( b.key )` instead of a boolean comparison operator.

Comment: Great answer, thx.

Comment: I'm assuming your `order` variable refers to `var order = ["c", "a", "b", "d"];
`?

Answer (score 19):

```js
const obj = [
    {
        key: "a",
        value: 42
    },
    {
        key: "d",
        value: 28
    },
    {
        key: "c",
        value: 92
    },
    {
        key: "b",
        value: 87
    }
]


const sortList = ["c", "a", "b", "d"];
    
    
const sortedObj = obj.sort((a, b) => {
    return (
        sortList.indexOf(a.key) - sortList.indexOf(b.key)
    );
});

console.log(sortedObj );
```

Answer (score 3):

I can't claim that this is the *most* efficient way, but you can use the `key` for each object as a key for properties in another object.  Then simply access them by these keys.

```
for (x = 0; x < objn.length; x++) {
    newobj[objn[x].key] = objn[x];
}
objn = [];
for (x = 0; x < keys.length; x++) {
    objn.push(newobj[keys[x]]);
}
console.log(objn);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WdehF/

Answer (score 2):

```
const data = [{key:"a"},{key:"d"},{key:"c"},{key:"b"}]      // <-your data
const order = ["c", "a", "b", "d"]          // <-create an array in the order you wish
const orderedArray = order.map(char=>data.find(res=>res.key===char))     // <- what you want
```

For each **char** in **order**: it will **map** if the **char** is equal to any **key** found within your **data**, and return it, consecutively

Answer (score 1):

```
// create hash map el.key -> index, to help us with direct access, avoid searching
const hashMap = arr.reduce((acc, el, index) => { acc[el.id] = el; return acc }, {})

// finally, map the ids to the final result
const ids.map(id => hashMap[id])
```