# Javascript - Order array of Json objects by key value

Tags: javascript

I have the following array of JSON objects:

```
[
  {
    term: 'summer'
  },
  {
    term: 'winter'
  },
  {
    term: 'fall'
  },
  {
    term: 'summer'
  },
  {
    term: 'summer'
  }
]
```

I was wondering how can order this array to be arranged by specific order of the `term` keys. For example the requested order is object with `winter` will be first then `fall` and then `summer`.
So the expected result should be:

```
[
  {
    term: 'winter'
  },
  {
    term: 'fall'
  },
  {
    term: 'summer'
  },
  {
    term: 'summer'
  },
  {
    term: 'summer'
  }
]
```

Please advise how can I order the array to result in the expected array.

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON. That's just an array of objects, no JSON in sight.

Comment: Please [search thoroughly](/search?q=%5Bjs%5D+sort+object+array) before posting. More about searching [here](/help/searching).

Comment: [Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) is typically employed like in `a.sort((o1, o2)=>seasons.indexOf(o1.term) - seasons.indexOf(o2.term))` where `seasons` should be your season names in the funny order you want, i.e., ["winter", "fall", "summer"] :-?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder the sorting I need it not alphabetical or ascending/descending , its in a specific order. Unfortunately the examples in your link do not answer the need.

Comment: @kikon the sorting I need it not alphabetical or ascending/descending , its in a specific order. Unfortunately the examples in your link do not answer the need.

Comment: Where is `spring`?

Comment: You can create a second array with the elements in the order that you want like this `const orderArray = ['winter', 'fall', 'summer'];` and then compare it with your current array. I would gladly answer but question was closed

Comment: @DavidFaizulaev - try it out - it does sort in your desired order. `Array.sort`'s argument is a function that implements your condition. It doesn't have to be neither numerical nor alphabetical - and it isn't in the example code I posted

Comment: @DavidFaizulaev - There are several with such a restriction as well. Sorry I marked the wrong one originally.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I searched for similar posts but was unable to find them. Apologize for any inconvenience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Array#sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) with a custom comparer function like so:

```js
const data = [
  {
    term: 'summer'
  },
  {
    term: 'winter'
  },
  {
    term: 'fall'
  },
  {
    term: 'summer'
  },
  {
    term: 'summer'
  }
]

const SEASON_ORDER = ['winter', 'fall', 'summer', 'spring']

const seasonComparer = ({term: a}, {term: b}) => 
    SEASON_ORDER.indexOf(a) - SEASON_ORDER.indexOf(b)

console.log(data.sort(seasonComparer))
```

For custom comparer functions with parameters `a` and `b`, if the return value is:

- greater than `0`, then `a` is sorted to be after `b`
- less than `0`, then `a` is sorted to be before `b`
- equal to `0`, then the existing order is maintained

Note that if the ordering list is large, then you might like to use a map instead (constant time), to avoid the O(N) look-up time associated with `Array#indexOf`.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18859186/sorting-an-array-of-javascript-objects-a-specific-order-using-existing-function and probably several others.